# 2022 Ford Edge fuse tap

Tags: fuse, tap

I can get the fuses out, and even put the a new fuse in, however i can not they the fuse tap to push in the slot? It is the same size, both micro 2 fuses come out and go in easily no explanation why I can’t get this in. Should be a simple job[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: For my clarity - you have bought a fuse tap with (supposedly) the right size to go into the car's fuse box, but it will not fit? They can be a tight fit, and sometimes the fuse box does not cooperate very well. A different brand of tap may work better, but that can be hard to figure out without trying several (which costs $$$).

Comment: That is correct. When taking the original fuse out of the vehicle it fits nicely into the fuse tap. The fuse tap itself however will not go into the panel. I took the fuse out of the tap and was able to replace it into the panel. I may need to try a different brand see if that works more easily. It is an Edge and not very accessible

Comment: Can you tell if the fuse tap is hitting another fuse or ridge in the fuse box? I've used one fuse tap, and worried about clearances/obstruction, but it managed to fit. Sorry yours did not.